# How to recompile react native app without rebundling assets

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native app, but on its native side.
If I run `react-native run-android` or `run-ios` it will first build
the native packages, to then start and complete the packager (at least for production). This process takes a long time. Is there a way to tell the script to use the latest built version of the assets, and just recompule the native binaries?

EDIT: I found out that you can add `org.gradle.configureondemand=true` to your `gradle.properties`, in order to skip *bundleJsAndAssets*. However, I can't find how to add the assets manually later.

Answer (score 0):

you can install `Webstorm IDE` and then install `React Native Console` plugins for this.
Finally, link to the your project.

It's likely that you can see what you want